# How do I run an on-the-fly ffmpeg (pipe) conversion in parallel?

Tags: bash, pipe, ffmpeg, parallelism

I want to do the following conversion:

```
for f in *.m4a; do 
    (  ffmpeg -i "$f" -f wav - | opusenc --bitrate 38 - "${f%.m4a}.opus" ) & 
done
```

I know I could use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) directly to convert to opus, but I want to use [opusenc](https://mf4.xiph.org/jenkins/view/opus/job/opus-tools/ws/man/opusenc.html) in this case, since it's a newer version.

When I run opusenc after the ffmpeg it works fine, but when I try to run the above I just get a bunch of `Stopped` and nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use GNU Parallel then this works:

```
parallel 'ffmpeg -i {} -f wav - | opusenc --bitrate 38 - {.}.opus' ::: *m4a
```

Maybe that is good enough?

It has the added benefit that it only runs 1 job per cpu thread, so if you have 1000 files you will not overload your machine.

Comment: Please see this for installation: https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this construction `(... &)` but I am not sure why it works:

```
for f in R*.mp3
do
  (time ffmpeg -loglevel 0 -i "$f" -ac 1 -y "${f%mp3}new.mp3" && date && ls -l "$f" &)
done
```

With 4 files:

```
real    0m0.784s
user    0m0.795s
sys     0m0.048s
So 10 Sep 2023 16:36:43 UTC
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1363436   10.Sep 10:04  REC-005.mp3

real    0m1.037s
user    0m1.064s
sys     0m0.040s
So 10 Sep 2023 16:36:43 UTC
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1540076   10.Sep 10:04  REC-003.mp3

real    0m1.822s
user    0m1.882s
sys     0m0.055s
So 10 Sep 2023 16:36:44 UTC
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2948588   10.Sep 10:04  REC-002.mp3

real    0m2.196s
user    0m2.253s
sys     0m0.061s
So 10 Sep 2023 16:36:44 UTC
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3402476   10.Sep 10:04  REC-004.mp3
```

The largest file ends last. I have `time` and a bash-`list`. But without (...&) I also get "Stopped" jobs (with unexpandend variables).